# Why can't I get the background colors to render?

Tags: javascript, rest, javascriptmvc

I'm trying to render the background colors from the exported const according to the PokeAPI but I don't know why the colors don't render. I'm using three files. model.js, controller.js, and view.js. I have my project in an MVC architecture.

This is model.js

```
export const state = {
    pokemon: {},
    search: {
        query: '',
        results: [],
        page: 1,
        resultsPerPage: 100,
    },
};

const fetchJson = (url) =>
    fetch(url)
        .then((r) => r.json())
        .catch(console.log);
export const loadPokemon = async () => {
    const [arrayA, arrayB] = await Promise.all([
        Promise.all(
            new Array(1008)
                .fill(0)
                .map((_, i) => fetchJson(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${i + 1}`))
        ),
        Promise.all(
            new Array(151)
                .fill(0)
                .map((_, i) =>
                    fetchJson(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/${i + 1}`)
                )
        ),
    ]);

    state.pokemon = arrayA.map((poke) => {
        return {
            name: poke.name,
            image: poke.sprites.front_default,
            types: poke.types,
        };
    });

    console.log(arrayA);
    console.log(arrayB);

};
export const typeColor = {
    bug: '#26de81',
    dragon: '#ffeaa7',
    electric: '#fed330',
    fairy: '#FF0069',
    fighting: '#30336b',
    fire: '#f0932b',
    flying: '#81ecec',
    grass: '#00b894',
    ground: '#EFB549',
    ghost: '#a55eea',
    ice: '#74b9ff',
    normal: '#95afc0',
    poison: '#6c5ce7',
    psychic: '#a29bfe',
    rock: '#2d3436',
    water: '#0190FF',
};
```

This is the controller

```
import * as model from './model.js';
import resultView from './views/resultsView.js';
import View from './Views/View.js';

const controlPokemon = async function () {
    try {
        await model.loadPokemon();

        resultView.render(model.state.pokemon);

        const typeData = model.state.pokemon.map((poke) => {
            return poke.types[0].type.name;
        });
        console.log(typeData);
        const themeColor = model.typeColor[typeData[0]];

        resultView.styleCard(themeColor);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};

const init = function () {
    resultView.addHandlerRender(controlPokemon);
};
init();
```

This is resultView.js

```
import View from './View.js';

class ResultsView extends View {
    _parentElement = document.querySelector('.results');
    _card = document.querySelector('.card');

    _generateMarkup() {
        console.log(this._data);
        return this._data.map(this._generateMarkupPreview).join('');
    }

    addHandlerRender(handler) {
        ['load'].forEach((ev) => window.addEventListener(ev, handler));
    }

    styleCard(color){
        return (this._card.style.background = `radial-gradient(circle at 50% 0%, ${color} 36%, #ffffff 36%)`);
    };

    _generateMarkupPreview(result) {
        return `
    <li class="preview">
        <a class="preview__link preview__link--active" href="#2343"></a>
            <div class="card">
            <p class="hp"><span>HP</span>80</p>
            figure class="preview__fig">
            <img class="fig" src="${result.image}" />
            </figure>
                        <h4 class="txt-description">${result.name[0].toUpperCase() + result.name.slice(1)
            }</h4>
            <div class="types">
            <span>${result.types[0]?.type.name[0].toUpperCase() +
                    result.types[0].type.name.slice(1)
                }</span>
            <span>${result.types[1]?.type.name}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="stats">
                    <div>
                        <h3>60</h3>
                        <p>Attack</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                        <h3>60</h3>
                            <p>Defense</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h3>60</h3>
                    <p>Speed</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>`;
    }
}

export default new ResultsView();
```

I'll add View.js just in case

```
export default class View {
    _data;

    render(data) {
        if (!data || (Array.isArray(data) && data.length === 0))
            return this.renderError();

        this._data = data;
        const markup = this._generateMarkup();
        this._clear();
        this._parentElement.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', markup);
    }

    _clear() {
        this._parentElement.innerHTML = '';
    }
}
```

That's all the files.

I consoled log the resultView.styleCard in the controller and saw the color was changed but it doesn't render the color in the UI. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few places where things can go wrong here.

First of all, try to check that `themeColor` has a meaningful value between these two lines:

```
const themeColor = model.typeColor[typeData[0]];

resultView.styleCard(themeColor);
```

Secondly, try to check what `radial-gradient(circle at 50% 0%, ${color} 36%, #ffffff 36%)` equals to before assigning it to the `this._card.style.background` within the following function:

```
styleCard(color){
  return (this._card.style.background = `radial-gradient(circle at 50% 0%, ${color} 36%, #ffffff 36%)`);
};
```

Finally, please check that `this._card.style.background` exists and returns the actual element before assigning a new background to it. You can just `console.log(this._card);` to see if the element is assigned.

Comment: For the first one. I consoled logged themeColor and got #00b894 according to the data from the PokeAPI. Which is the color coming from model. The second one I'm unsure. For the last part I consoled logged this._card and the element exists and shows that it changed the color.

Comment: @Alazy99 do you actually see the card on the screen? Does it have valid dimensions? Could it be covered with something? Do you see that the card changes color if you change its `background` value in the browser element inspector manually? I cannot run the code above to see the problem. Would you be able to create a minimal code snippet reproducing the problem?

Comment: I've checked and realized it's not in the same method as the one below. So it was not on the screen. I was creating a new card. It was working but rendered it wrong. I did finally figure it out on my own and all the colors render properly now. Thank you for the comment! I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Alazy99 No worries! Happy to help. Would you mind upvoting the comment if it was helpful? Thanks!

Comment: I can't upvote your comment. I don't see the up arrow. Is it because I'm still new to StackOverflow?

Comment: @Alazy99 My bad! You need to earn a bit more reputation points to do this. I totally forgot about this limitation. No worries! Thanks!